# Access control on firebase hosting test and staging

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-security, firebase-hosting

In Firebase you can deploy multiple sites, usually you have one GCP project for production and another for testing. The structure would look something like this:

**GCP Project: myproject-prod**

- Firebase Hosting

  - prod (publicly accessible)
  - stage (access restricted)

**GCP Project: myproject-test**

- Firebase Hosting

  - dev-latest (access restricted)
  - dev-feature (access restricted)

What's best practices for adding access control on Firebase hosting so only my developers can access the "access restricted" sites?